# Email from PHP mail() function does not work but ssh /usr/sbin/sendmail work

Tags: php, email, ssh, sendmail

When i try to send email from the PHP using mail function, it doesn't work. I created a small text.txt file with contents

> From: admin@abc.com
>
> To: zee@xyc.com
>
> Subject: Test message
>
> This is a test message

and give command on ssh

> /usr/sbin/sendmail -t < test.txt

it works perfectly. I am using CentOS 6.5 64bit.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: has the sendmail_path php setting been set to the correct location?